# I'm recieving a TypeError because a NoneType object is not subscriptable. How do I make it subscriptable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write code for a text based RPG by following along in a book called *Make Your Own Python Text Adventure* by *Phillip Johnson*. I am having trouble identifying where the error lies in my code. I've gone through it several times and can't seem to figure it out. I've tried fiddling with different things but so far it just gives different errors. I'll post my code and the Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\Yradel_Game5.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\Yradel_Game5.py", line 31, in main
    player = Player()
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Hall\Desktop\Yradel_Game\player.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

*Yradel_Game5.py*

```
# this program is a text based rpg

#import the OrderedDict
from collections import OrderedDict

# import the player module
from player import Player

# import the world module
import world

def main():
    # display Yradellian name examples
    print("Some examples of female Yradellian names include Nelsi, Drew, Casey, Ilya, etc.")
    print("Some examples of male Yradellian names include Toreth, Daren, Attel, Mayes, etc.")

    # get the character name from the user
    yesName = False
    while yesName == False:
        charName = input("What can I call you? ")
        nameInput = input("Your name is, " + charName + "? Type Yes or No: ")
        if nameInput == "Yes":
            yesName = True
        else:
            print("Sorry...")

    # call the parse world function
    world.parse_world_dsl()

    # create a player object
    player = Player()

    # display the welcome message
    print()
    player.say_hello(charName)

    # display current inventory
    print()
    print("Here's your starting game Inventory:")
    player.print_inventory()

    while True:
        # display the intro text for each tile
        print()
        room = world.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
        print(room.intro_text())

        # modify the player depending on the tile type
        room.modify_player(player)

        # get the action input from the user
        print()

        choose_action(room, player)
# create a funtion for available actions
def get_available_actions(room, player):
    actions = OrderedDict()
    print("Choose what to do...")

    if player.inventory:
        action_adder(actions, "i", player.print_inventory, "Print inventory")
    if isinstance(room, world.TraderTile):
        action_adder(actions, "t", player.trade, "Trade")
    if isinstance(room, world.EnemyTile) and room.enemy.is_alive():
        action_adder(actions, "a", player.attack, "Attack")
    else:
        if world.tile_at(room.x, room.y - 1):
            action_adder(actions, "n", player.move_north, "Go North!")
        if world.tile_at(room.x + 1, room.y):
            action_adder(actions, "e", player.move_east, "Go East!")
        if world.tile_at(room.x, room.y + 1):
            action_adder(actions, "s", player.move_south, "Go South!")
        if world.tile_at(room.x - 1, room.y):
            action_adder(actions, "w", player.move_west, "Go West!")
    if player.hp < 100:
        action_adder(actions, "h", player.heal, "Heal")

    return actions

# create the action adder function
def action_adder(action_dict, hotkey, action, name):
    action_dict[hotkey.lower()] = action
    action_dict[hotkey.upper()] = action
    print("{}: {}".format(hotkey, name))

# create a function to utilize the action dictionary
def choose_action(room, player):
    action = None
    while not action:
        available_actions = get_available_actions(room, player)
        action_input = input("Action: (Type a letter) ")
        action = available_actions.get(action_input)
        if action:
            action()
        else:
            print("That is invalid input.")

# call the main function
main()
```

*world.py*

```
# import the enemies module
import enemies
# import the npc module
import npc
# import the random module
import random

# create a parent class for the map tiles
class MapTile:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def intro_text(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Create a subclass instead!")
    def modify_player(self, player):
        pass

# create the tile subclasses
class StartTile(MapTile):
    def intro_text(self):
        return """You find yourself in a forest, sunlight trickling through the leaves overhead. Your feet crunch over the underbrush. You can see four paths through the trees.\n"""

class BoringTile(MapTile):
    def intro_text(self):
        return """The trees all look the same here...\n"""

class CityTile(MapTile):
    def intro_text(self):
        return """You made it out of the forest into a small town known as Burenburg. The people greet you warmly and you are filled with a sense of accomplishment.\n"""

class EnemyTile(MapTile):
    # have enemies randomly appear
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        r = random.random()
        if r < 0.50:
            self.enemy = enemies.Wolf()
            self.alive_text = "A lone Wolf approaches you baring its fangs."
            self.dead_text = "The Wolf keels over, dead before you."
        else:
            self.enemy = enemies.Goblin()
            self.alive_text = "A Goblin tries to steal your gold, you must defend yourself against his blade."
            self.dead_text = "The Goblin sticks its tongue out at you as it falls over dead."
        super().__init__(x, y)
    # display their alive/dead message
    def intro_text(self):
        text = self.alive_text if self.enemy.is_alive() else self.dead_text
        return text
    # have enemies attack the player
    def modify_player(self, player):
        if self.enemy.is_alive():
            player.hp = player.hp - self.enemy.damage
            print("Enemy does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".format(self.enemy.damage, player.hp))

class TraderTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.trader = npc.Trader()
        super().__init__(x, y)
    # create a method to trade between a buyer and seller
    def trade(self, buyer, seller):
        for i, item in enumerate(seller.inventory, 1):
            print("{}. {} - {} Gold".format(i, item.name, item.value))
        while True:
            user_input = input("Choose an item or press Q to exit: ")
            if user_input in ["Q", "q"]:
                return
            else:
                try:
                    choice = int(user_input)
                    to_swap = seller.inventory[choice - 1]
                    self.swap(seller, buyer, to_swap)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid choice!")
    # create a method to swap items and gold between the buyer and seller
    def swap(self, seller, buyer, item):
        if item.value > buyer.gold:
            print("That's too expensive")
            return
        seller.inventory.remove(item)
        buyer.inventory.append(item)
        seller.gold = seller.gold + item.value
        buyer.gold = buyer.gold - item.value
        print("Trade complete!")
    # create a method to accept user input about who is the buyer and seller
    def check_if_trade(self, player):
        while True:
            print("Would you like to (B)uy, (S)ell or (Q)uit?")
            user_input = input()
            if user_input in ["Q", "q"]:
                return
            elif user_input in ["B", "b"]:
                print("Here's what's available to buy: ")
                self.trade(buyer = player, seller = self.trader)
            elif user_input in ["S", "s"]:
                print("Here's what's available to sell: ")
                self.trade(buyer = self.trader, seller = player)
            else:
                print("Invalid choice!")
    # create intro text for this room
    def intro_text(self):
        return """A man in a brown robe awaits you, willing to trade."""

class GoldTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.gold = random.randint(1, 50)
        self.gold_claimed = False
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def modify_player(self, player):
        if not self.gold_claimed:
            self.gold_claimed = True
            player.gold = player.gold + self.gold
            print("+{} Gold added.".format(self.gold))

    def intro_text(self):
        if self.gold_claimed:
            return """Another clearing in the forest with nothing in it but cute animals and underbrush."""
        else:
            return """Someone must've dropped some gold! You pick it up."""

# create the basic world map
world_dsl = """
| |E|C|E| |
|B|B| |B| |
|T| |G|E|B|
|G| |E| |G|
|E|B|S|T|B|
| | |E| |G|
| | |G|B|E|
"""

# create a function to validate the dsl
def is_dsl_valid(dsl):
    if dsl.count("|S|") != 1:
        return False
    if dsl.count("|C|") == 0:
        return False
    lines = dsl.splitlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if l]
    pipe_counts = [line.count("|") for line in lines]
    for count in pipe_counts:
        if count != pipe_counts[0]:
            return False

    return True

# define a dictionary that maps dsl abreviations to tile types
tile_type_dict = {"C": CityTile,
                  "E": EnemyTile,
                  "S": StartTile,
                  "B": BoringTile,
                  "G": GoldTile,
                  "T": TraderTile,
                  " ": None}

world_map = []

start_tile_location = None

# create the function to parse the dsl
def parse_world_dsl():
    if not is_dsl_valid(world_dsl):
        raise SyntaxError("DSL is invalid!")

    dsl_lines = world_dsl.splitlines()
    dsl_lines = [x for x in dsl_lines if x]

    # iterate over each line in the dsl
    # instead of i, the variable y is used because we're working with an X-Y grid.
    for y, dsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
        # create an object to store the tiles
        row = []
        # split the line into abbreviations using the "split" method
        dsl_cells = dsl_row.split("|")
        # the split method includes the beginning and end of the line
        # so we need to remove those nonexistent cells
        dsl_cells = [ c for c in dsl_cells if c]
        # iterate over each cell in the dsl line
        # instead of j, the variable x is used becuase we're working with an X-Y grid
        for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
            # look up the abbreviation in the dictionary
            tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
            # if the dictionary returned a valid type, create a new
            # tile object, pass it the X-Y coordinates as required
            # by the tile__init__(), and add it to the row object. If
            # None was found in the dictionary, we just add None.
            row.append(tile_type(x, y) if tile_type else None)

        # add the whole row to the world_map
        world_map.append(row)

# create a function that locates the tile at a specific coordinate
def tile_at(x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return None
    try:
        return world_map[y][x]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

*player.py*

```
# import the items module
import items
# import the world module
import world

# create a class for Player
class Player:
    # define the inventory
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = [items.Dagger(), items.BreadRoll(), items.Potion()]
        self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
        self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
        self.hp = 100
        self.gold = 100
    # print the inventory and the best weapon
    def print_inventory(self):
        print("Inventory:")
        for item in self.inventory:
            print("* " + str(item))
        print("Gold: {}".format(self.gold))
        best_weapon = self.most_powerful_weapon()
        print("Your best weapon is your {}".format(best_weapon))
    # create a function to heal the player
    def heal(self):
        consumables = [item for item in self.inventory if isinstance(item, items.Consumable)]
        if not consumables:
            print("You don't have any items to heal you!")
            return
        for i, item in enumerate(consumables, 1):
            print("Choose an item to use to heal: ")
            print("{}. {}".format(i, item))
        valid = False
        while not valid:
            choice = input("")
            try:
                to_eat = consumables[int(choice) - 1]
                self.hp = min(100, self.hp + to_eat.healing_value)
                self.inventory.remove(to_eat)
                print("Current HP: {}".format(self.hp))
                valid = True
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                print("Invalid choice, try again.")
    # welcome the user to the game
    def say_hello(self, name):
        print("Hello, " + name, ", welcome to the world of Yradel.")
    # create a function to determine the best weapon
    def most_powerful_weapon(self):
        max_damage = 0
        best_weapon = None
        for item in self.inventory:
            try:
                if item.damage > max_damage:
                    best_weapon = item
                    max_damage = item.damage
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        return best_weapon
    # create functions to let the player move
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
    def move_north(self):
        self.move(dx = 0, dy = -1)
    def move_east(self):
        self.move(dx = 1, dy = 0)
    def move_south(self):
        self.move(dx = 0, dy = 1)
    def move_west(self):
        self.move(dx = -1, dy = 0)
    # create a function to attack the enemy
    def attack(self):
        best_weapon = self.most_powerful_weapon()
        room = world.tile_at(self.x, self.y)
        enemy = room.enemy
        print("You use {} against the {}!".format(best_weapon.name, enemy.name))
        enemy.hp -= best_weapon.damage
        if not enemy.is_alive():
            print("You killed {}!".format(enemy.name))
        else:
            print("{} HP is {}.".format(enemy.name, enemy.hp))
    # create a method to allow trade
    def trade(self):
        room = world.tile_at(self.x, self.y)
        room.check_if_trade(self)
```

Comment: The error means that `world.start_tile_location` is None, its just a case of searching for it. You initialize it to `world.start_tile_location = None` and you don't change that.

Comment: This error is easy to look up,  See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  As far as you've posted here, you really haven't done much to trace the problem in your code.

Comment: Just want to let you know, as I said in the body, I looked through my code several times before I posted this question. I'm still new to coding and this stuff has been a bit complicated. I'm trying to learn the best I can and sometimes it can be hard. That article you posted advises to look through your code and explain to yourself what it's supposed to do and if you can't then there's the error. (Rubber duck method). However, that's what I did and still couldn't find the error which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to set `start_tile_location` in this function:

```py
start_tile_location = None

# create the function to parse the dsl
def parse_world_dsl():
    if not is_dsl_valid(world_dsl):
        raise SyntaxError("DSL is invalid!")

    dsl_lines = world_dsl.splitlines()
    dsl_lines = [x for x in dsl_lines if x]

    # iterate over each line in the dsl
    # instead of i, the variable y is used because we're working with an X-Y grid.
    for y, dsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
        # create an object to store the tiles
        row = []
        # split the line into abbreviations using the "split" method
        dsl_cells = dsl_row.split("|")
        # the split method includes the beginning and end of the line
        # so we need to remove those nonexistent cells
        dsl_cells = [ c for c in dsl_cells if c]
        # iterate over each cell in the dsl line
        # instead of j, the variable x is used becuase we're working with an X-Y grid
        for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
            # look up the abbreviation in the dictionary
            tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
            # if the dictionary returned a valid type, create a new
            # tile object, pass it the X-Y coordinates as required
            # by the tile__init__(), and add it to the row object. If
            # None was found in the dictionary, we just add None.
            row.append(tile_type(x, y) if tile_type else None)

            if "S" == dsl_cell:
                start_tile_location = (x, y)

        # add the whole row to the world_map
        world_map.append(row)
```